# How can I allow directory access to public

Tags: htaccess

I have a website with expressionengine. website struture is

/system

-- Codeigniter

---- system

-- expressionengine

/test

I have a folder test, I would like to make it accessible to public. I am not getting anything from htaccess.

How can I done it?

Answer (score 2):

First - I'm presuming you're serving on a Unix system. You'll require either shell access to the directory or s/FTP access that can change owner and permission

You have to give the public Read Access on the folder and the files (via chmod). You also might want to make sure the owner of the files only ('chown') are your web-user (often something like www-data).

Remember - read only, not write access (which is also delete access).

Look at [this brief tutorial from Dartmouth](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html) and get up to speed on how to open up permissions to your files, but seriously - use it with care. The wrong permissions and ownership can mean compromising your installation. Also, I would only allow access to a directory in the /images/uploads/ path - that's what it's intention is there for.

Comment: Did this work for you? If not, please let us know. If it did, could you please mark this as a correct response so other will know later? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Public directory aren't really the realm of ExpressionEngine, that's a basic website question, which maybe more appropriate for [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). That said, the general conditions for making a directory public is to make it *world writable* using permissions. World writable is consider `777` or `rwxrwxrwx` permissions.

Generally, your ISP will provide you some access to change permissions of files and directories within your public_html folder. Most FTP applications also provide the opportunity to visually change permissions, so that you don't need to know the unix `chmod` command. Obviously, there can be security implications for making a folder world readable, generally you don't want to allow executable files in those directors, more like images, pdfs, etc.